# php простое управление конфигом?

Tags: php

Есть ли php классы или встроенные функции возможно чтобы легко записывать туда данные 1-2 строками. Или же читать их так же?

Answer (score 2):

Если речь о .ini конфигах то в ПХП 
есть стандатрная функция для чтения:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Писать нужно или самому или воспользоваться

https://github.com/pear/Config_Lite.

Оно сразу и писать и читать умеет.